# Deleted ViewController.h and viewController.m from cocoa project

Tags: cocoa, uiviewcontroller

I did the move to trash option and now other files.h cannot import viewcontroller.h.  How do i get it back into my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using finder, move them out of the trash and back to your project directory with the rest of your source files, then, in xCode, `Right-Click` (Or two-fingered click on the touchpad) on a group and select `'Add Files to <Project Name>'`

Locate the files in the source directory (should be easy, the dialog box greys out files already in the project) and check the box `copy files into destination's group folder (if needed)`

Make sure in the `Add to targets` box that your target is highlighted (not the Tests one, just the main one) and then click the `Add` button

Comment: The “Add to targets” list contains targets, not projects.